# Load part of matfile error: 'VARName' does not exist

Tags: arrays, matlab, mat-file, matlab-load

i'm trying to load part of array in a matfile like is showed in http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matfile.html

however, when i use loadedData = matObj.varName(indices) i keep getting: 'varName' does not exist

someone knows what's rong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In place of *VarName* you should use the name of the actual variable you want to retrieve.

Suppose you have saved a variable `A` into `myMat`:

```
A      = rand(10);
save('myMat','A','-v7.3')

matObj = matfile('myMat');
data   = matObj.A(1:2,2);
```